# When does the call() method get called in a Java Executor using Callable objects?

Tags: java, concurrency

This is some sample code from an [example](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6). What I need to know is when `call()` gets called on the callable? What triggers it?

```
public class CallableExample {

public static class WordLengthCallable
    implements Callable {
    private String word;
    public WordLengthCallable(String word) {
      this.word = word;
    }
    public Integer call() {
      return Integer.valueOf(word.length());
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Set<Future<Integer>> set = new HashSet<Future<Integer>>();
    for (String word: args) {
      Callable<Integer> callable = new WordLengthCallable(word);
      Future<Integer> future = pool.submit(callable); //**DOES THIS CALL call()?**
      set.add(future);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (Future<Integer> future : set) {
      sum += future.get();//**OR DOES THIS CALL call()?**
    }
    System.out.printf("The sum of lengths is %s%n", sum);
    System.exit(sum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Once you have `submitted` the callable, the executor will schedule the callable for execution. Depending on the executor this might happen directly or once a thread becomes available.

Calling `get` on the other hand only waits to retrieve the result of the computation.

So to be precise: Somewhere in-between `submit` being called and the call to `get` returning, the callable is called.

Answer (score 4):

The entire idea of using an `Executor` is that you shouldn't care *when exactly* the method is called.

The only thing that is guaranteed in general is that the method will have executed when `get()` of the `Future` returns.

When exactly it will be called depends on which `Executor` you use. With the fixed thread pool you use in the example, the `call()` method will be called as soon as there is a free thread and no other task is in front of the given task in the queue (so as long as there are enough tasks, you'll have 3 `call()` method calls running at any given time in your example).

Comment: i understand the issue about threads becoming available at an unpredictable time, i should have asked 'when will a callable be **scheduled** ' - as long as it gets scheduled on *submit()* then that's all i needed to know :)

Comment: @Malcom: I don't think that that would be a better question, since the scheduling is not visible/observable to the program, so what would change when the if it were scheduled at a later time?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "when will a callable be schedules" lies in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#execute implementation (the default)